# MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE limits my import?

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I try to import data from a CSV to MySQL. For this I run mysql and log in with:

```
mysql -u USER -p --local-infile=1 DATABASE
```

and import data with:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/USER/FILENAME.csv' 
INTO TABLE TABLENAME 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

First I thought everything is fine because the data was loaded and looked good so far but then I got some problems and found out that strings are limited to 32756 characters in my longtext column. So I'm sure I forgot something but couldn't find the answer until know :(

Comment: Sample data? Table definition? More details?

Comment: Have you checked the source line for any of the offending rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html):

> If strict SQL mode is not enabled and you assign a value to a BLOB or
> TEXT column that exceeds the column's maximum length, the value is
> truncated to fit and a warning is generated. For truncation of
> nonspace characters, you can cause an error to occur (rather than a
> warning) and suppress insertion of the value by using strict SQL mode.
>
> LONGBLOB, LONGTEXT    L + 4 bytes, where L < 2^32

My **guess** is that you're using a multibyte encoding and so are running into length problems. You've further not set [strict SQL mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html) to error out when this is the case. Hope that helps and, as always, if you've further questions, do leave a comment.

Comment: For 2^32 = 4294967296 `LONGTEXT` should store at least 1073741824 chaacters with 4 bytes each. I don't think, that there is an encoding in MySQL with more bytes per character...

Comment: @TheConstructor depending on how much OP is shoving into mysql, this could be a problem.

Comment: Of course, but OP can only store up to 32756 characters which is far less.

Comment: Then perhaps OP isn't using LONGTEXT?

Comment: I will further note that you're not giving an answer here, you're merely attacking mine

Comment: I was tying to find a reason why this happens, provided that OP is using a `LONGTEXT` column, as was stated in the question. I wouldn't have bothered you if you had included that `TEXT` is L + 2 bytes, where L < 2^16 and had suggested that OP might accidentally have used a `TEXT` instead of the desired `MEDIUMTEXT` or `LONGTEXT`. I would see this as pointing out that you don't cover the whole thing.

Comment: @TheConstructor if you looked at the link, you would have seen that it does cover TEXT and MEDIDUMTEXT within. Indeed, you could have suggested an edit to my answer, instead you start off in pissing contest which is unproductive **at best**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58732/discussion-between-theconstructor-and-hd1).